# can use strings as X axis labels in jsx graph

Tags: jsxgraph

I am trying to draw a graph exactly like this using JSX graph library: [image]

but i stucked at changing x axis variables to texts..

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the time being, this is not possible out of the box. There are two easy possibilities: Either you place the labels **above** the bars. This can be done by using the `labels` attribute:

```
var a = board.create('chart', dataArr, {
    chartStyle: 'bar',
    width: 0.6,
    labels: ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse'],
    hasInnerPoints: true,
    label: {
        fontSize: 16
    }
});
```

The other option is to but text elements "by hand" below the axis:

```
board.create('text', [1, -0.5,  'cat'], {});
board.create('text', [2, -0.5,  'dog'], {});
board.create('text', [3, -0.5,  'mouse'], {});
```